# How to disable the "Meet the Dropbox badge" dialog?

Tags: windows-7, dropbox

Lately, a dropbox dialogbox that says "Meet the Dropbox badge" pops up randomly when I move my mouse towards the right side of the screen. The dialog box looks like this:

[image]

It's kind of disturbing, and I was wondering if anyone knows how to disable it?

Note: I have clicked `Preferences` in the dialog and unchecked the `Show Desktop Notifications` option. But it still shows up. Also, it seems to show up when MS Office, e.g. PowerPoint is on focus, and mouse is on right-edge. When FireFox is on focus and occupies the screen, it does not show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution further down in the `Preference` dialog.

There is an option below the option group `Show Desktop Notifications` about the Meet the Dropbox badge option. After choosing `Never show` from the dropbox, the problem seems to have been solved.

Comment: Does this also disable the desktop notifications? I like the old style taskbar notifications when someone else updates a file.